# Forms action - Error 404 - not found

Tags: php

I am trying to send a email using forms and PHP. When I click on the send button I get t the error Error occurred: 404 - not found. submit.php file is in same dir as the webpage. Why can't it find the submit.php. My html code.

```
<form action="submit.php" id="form1" method="post">
<fieldset>              
    <label class="input">Date:<span><span><input type="text" id="datepicker" value=""/></span></span></label>
    <label class="input">Enter Your Name:<span><span><input name="name"/></span></span></label>
    <label class="input">Enter Your Email:<span><span><input name="email"/></span></span></label>
    <label class="input">Subject:<span><span><input name="subject"/></span></span></label>
    <label class="text">Enter Your Message:<span><span><textarea name="comment" cols="0" rows="0"></textarea></span></span></label>
    <label class="input">Enter Code:<img src="php/captcha.php"><span><span><input type="text" name="vercode" /></span></span></label>
    <label class="butt"><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').reset()" class="button"><strong><b>clear</b></strong></a>
    <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit()" class="button"><strong><b>send</b></strong></a></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Do you ever close with `</form>`?

Answer (score 0):

When using `<a>`'s to use as form submit buttons, I would suggest using a JavaScript function and put it in the `onclick` of the anchor. Like this:

```js
function doSubmit(form_name) {
  // check if the object exists
  if (document.getElementById(form_name)) {

    // submit the form
    document.getElementById(form_name).submit();
  }

  // prevent the link from clicking
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="return doSubmit('form1');" class="button"><strong><b>send</b></strong></a>
```

The same can be done for the reset button.

In this way, you never navigate your browser to a "javascript:...etc.." location (that does not exist). I'm not sure if this is the case here, but just as a best practice advise then. :)